# Getting the list of distinct years gives error: Can't convert from BSON to Date

Tags: mongodb, date, distinct

I have a collection called: 'archives' that stores the dates inside the header.date object. The dates look something like this:

```
"2003-06-22T07:40:17+00:00"
"2003-06-22T21:16:52+10:00"
```

I am trying to get the list of distinct years using this query, but it returns:
**Error: Can't convert from BSON type string to Date.**

Is there any way to fix it in the query, instead of changing the DB format?

```
db.archives.aggregate([
    { $group : {
            _id : { year : { $year : "$header.date" }},
            total : { $sum : 1 }
        }},
    { $sort : {"_id.year" : 1}}
])
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, here is the answer, I figured it out on my own, eventually.
The timestamp is handled as a string, so I needed to use regex to extract the year only before I could group it:

```
db.archives.aggregate(
    { $group : {
            _id: {
                year :  { $substr : ["$header.date", 0, 4 ] }
            },
            count: { $sum: 1 }
        }
    },
    { $sort : { _id : 1}}
    );
```